# Нужны ли запятые в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

> Я тут(,) рядом с тобой(,) так усердно работаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно "Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §79. Уточняющие члены предложения выделяются запятыми. Относясь к тому или иному слову  в предложении, они сужают обозначаемое ими понятие или в каком-либо отношении ограничивают его. Чаще всего значение уточнения приобретают обстоятельства места, времени, образа действия, степени, меры.

Соответственно:

*Я тут, рядом с тобой, так усердно работаю...*

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: Вполне возможен контекст без запятых (при определённой интонации). Ср. для примера: *Звать меня ― Роман Львович, я тут рядом с вами в доме отдыха имени Цюрупы.* (Ю. Домбровский)

Comment: Вот простой пример, в котором запятая будет совсем уж неуместна: *я тут рядом живу* (интонацией выделяется не *тут*, а *рядом*). Теперь добавьте с продолжением возрастающей интонации "с вами": *я тут рядом с вами живу*. (Это всё только в разговорном стиле возможно, наверное).